# How disable getting data from related model in Yii

Tags: activerecord, yii

I don't need to get data from related model.
I have model Post
Also i have model Comment.

Every Post has comments.
I make related between models so:

```
class Post
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            'comments' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Comment', 'post_id')
        );
    }

    public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'orderDesc'=>array(
                'order' => 'post_id DESC',
            ),
        );

    }

    public function findAllPosts()
    {
        return $this->orderDesc()->findAll();
    }
```

If i get post from db I need comments - no problem.

```
Post::model()->findByPk()
```

But if i get all Posts - I don't need comments

```
Post::model()->findAllPosts()
```

But i get posts with comments. I think - it's not good for database - use additional joins and it's interesting fo me how disable getting data from related model.

I tried make so through scenario and change behaviour in method relations, but in method relations i got always - $this->scenario is empty.

Comment: How are you determining that you do in fact get posts with comments? Unless that relation is included in the model's `defaultScope` or using `with`, it will *not* be automatically loaded.

Comment: If i do
$posts = Post::model()->findAll();
CVarDumper::dump($posts[0]->comments)
I get comments for this post

Comment: That's because Yii [lazy loads the comments for you](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query). If you don't access `comments`, it won't be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Yii the defined relations are by default loaded lazy loading.
It means that Yii will fetch the related models only when you call them in your code.

So if you do

```
Post::model()->findAll();
```

The related models (ie: comments) won't be loaded. But if your a calling

```
Post::model()->findAll();
CVarDumper::dump($posts[0]->comments);
```

Then a second DB request will be performed to fetch the related comments. This is why the code display the comments.

If you know that you are going to need a related model, the best solution is to use eager loading: it consists in loading the related models in the same request that load the initial model. To do it you need to specify the `with` method in your code.

Example:

```
Post::model()->with('comments')->findAll();
```

This method `with` can also be put in a defined scope in your model or in the default scope. If it's in the default scope then every time a model is loaded, his related models will be loaded in the same request.

A last note:

When you are using eager loading, one request is performed to fetch the related models, but this technique could not be perfect for every relation.

For example if you have a `post` and you want to load the `author` profile, since there is only one `author`, the request will be fast, returning only one line so the eager loading is good.

But then you want to load the `comments`. Since it's performing only one request, you'll have severals lines containing a lot of similar informations (all the informations about the `post`). In this case the pure eager loading is not the best solution.
The best way to handle those relations is to specify in the relations array the params `together` to false.
If you do so, 2 request will be performed: a first one to fetch the `post` and a second one to fetch the related `comments`.

Example:

```
Post::model()->with('comments' => array('together' => false))->findAll();
```

Source: [Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr)